# passing value to get_context_data from Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a Django template associated with a particular model. Within the view for this template, I am trying to access a record from a different model (Terms containing scientific terms), based on the parameter I would pass in the template.

I tried being using `get_context_data` to query a random term in the database, and then use a custom filter tag to replace the term to the one I want from within the template. Django is smarter, though and wouldn't let me do that.

Currently, I am trying to define the context within my `views.py`

```
class ArticlesView(DetailView):
    model = models.Articles
    template_name = 'web/articles-details.html'
    context_object_name = 'Articles_details'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ArticlesView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['featured'] = Articles.objects.filter(featured=True)
        ctx['term','arg'] = Articles.objects.filter('slug'=='arg')
        return ctx
```

In the above code, the 'featured' context works fine, but not the 'term' one. It is clearly wrong; I know that... but I can't figure out what the correct syntax would be, and how I would provide the parameter from within the template. (I am trying to print out just the slug of the 'scientific term' in this example).

Any thoughts?

I know that I can set a `ForeignKey` within my models to connect them. The problem with that is that I would have at least 4-5 'scientific terms' on any given page, and therefore, I would have to add at least 5 related terms for each page, and then add them in a particular manner... a lot of repetition and messy.

Thanks for your assistance, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with the context won't quite work as you perhaps think. To illustrate what you've done with that context dictionary;

```
>>> context = dict()
>>> context['slug', 'arg'] = 'test'
>>> context
{('slug', 'arg'): 'test'}
>>> context['slug']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'slug'
>>> context['arg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'arg'
>>> context['slug', 'arg']
'test'
```

So in your template if you did something like {{ slug, arg }} you'd get your object, but I don't think that's valid in the template syntax.

So based on what you've got I suspect you'd want to do something like;

```
arg = 'my-slug'
ctx['term'] = Articles.objects.filter(slug=arg)
ctx['arg'] = arg
```

That would give you the `arg` used to match the slug on the `Articles` model with the queryset assigned to `term`.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. The explanation really helps with the understanding. In the approach you suggested, how would I call it from the template? say the slug I want to use is 'brain.' Would I use `{{ brain, arg }}` or `arg = 'brain'` in my template? or something else?

Comment: @RaghavSuri to be honest I didn't really understand why you were trying to assign two variables (`ctx['term','arg']`) so I'd recommend simplifying that to `ctx['term']` or `ctx['arg']`. Avoid doing `ctx['term','arg']` because it's probably not what you want to do.